# Yeoman angularjs scaffolding error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to run this command:

```
yo angular
```

But it gives me this error:

```
**/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:84
  if (_.isString(componentConfigFile.main)) {
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at findMainFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:84:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:146:17
    at forOwn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:1301:15)
    at Function.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2595:9)
    at detectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:28:5)
    at wiredep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:57:39)
    at Generator._injectDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js:326:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:113:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16**
```

How can I fix above error?
Note: I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Git was not installed, because yeoman tries to get bower_components via Git

Answer (score 0):

I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and came across this issue after installing and switching to the latest version of node. I realized I forgot to re-install [bower](http://bower.io/) globally:

```
npm install -g bower
```

After installing bower, the issue went away.